# How to add 'scrollTo' function to the Accordion in jQuery-ui-1.8.16 to focus on category header

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

This is my accordion: http://muso-syndicate.com/accordion/index9.htm - **N.B. only currently styled for SF, FF, doesn't currently work in IE**

If you select a 2nd category header once another one has been opened, it doesn't re-focus on the new header. By example, click on **'Classical'** then scroll down and select **'Jazz'**, it doesn't automatically scroll back up to the top of the 2nd category.

Ideally, I'd like to add a 'scrollTo' function to '.bind' to the jQuery UI library. However, I have tried various solutions suggested on StackOverflow but none seem to work for me!

As the categories will vary in height as more content is added, I'd prefer not to use a solution that uses a fixed pixel scrollTo solution as this will require constant altering as new content is added to each category.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as several folk seem to be scratching their heads on this one!

---

UPDATE:

I've got much closer to a solution for this but still requires some tweaking to stop the focus occasionally scrolling past the category header. Please see code below:

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#categories" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: -1,
        change: function(event, ui)
            {
            $("#categories").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui)
                {
                    $("#categories").animate({scrollTop: $(ui.newHeader).offset().top}, 1);
                });
            },

        });     
});
```

Comment: I've got much closer to a solution for this but still requires some tweaking to stop the focus occasionally missing the category header.